# Drawing figures in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

[image: Figure 1]

Can I make the figure which I just posted here in LaTeX?

Comment: Yes,for sure you can. Read about `tikz`. For example http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tex-workflow/

Comment: Have a look at the [`tikz-cd`](http://ctan.cms.math.ca/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf) package; it seems suitable for your purpose

Comment: I'd use TikZ-matrices to place nodes for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Making use of Claudio Fiandrino's suggestion to use a `matrix` to typeset the diagrams as well as the `subcaption` package and some `minipage`s, here's a way to implement the figure that you have in mind. Note the required `%`s in order to make sure that the first two `minipage`s appear next to each other rather than on top of each other.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

    \begin{minipage}[b]{.4\linewidth}
    \centering

        \begin{tikzpicture}

        \matrix[name=M, matrix of nodes, column sep=1cm, row sep=1cm]{
            \node[draw,minimum size=1cm]{IQ}; & \node[draw,minimum size=1cm]{Z}; \\
            \node[draw,minimum size=1cm]{JP}; & \node[draw,minimum size=1cm]{R}; \\
        };

        \draw[<->] (M-1-2) edge (M-2-2);
        \draw[<->] (M-1-1) edge (M-2-1);    
        \draw[<->] (M-1-1) edge (M-2-2);
        \draw[<->] (M-2-1) edge (M-2-2);

    \end{tikzpicture}

    \subcaption{MNAR Mechanism}\label{fig:1a}
    \end{minipage}%
%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.4\linewidth}
    \centering

        \begin{tikzpicture}

            \matrix[name=M, matrix of nodes, column sep=1cm, row sep=1cm]{
                \node[draw,minimum size=1cm]{IQ}; & \node[draw,minimum size=1cm]{Z}; \\
                \node[draw,minimum size=1cm]{JP}; & \node[draw,minimum size=1cm]{R}; \\
            };

            \draw[<->] (M-1-2) edge (M-2-2);
            \draw[<->] (M-1-1) edge (M-2-1);    
            \draw[<->] (M-1-1) edge (M-2-2);

        \end{tikzpicture}

    \subcaption{MAR Mechanism}\label{fig:1b}
    \end{minipage}

    \begin{minipage}[b]{.4\linewidth}
    \centering

        \begin{tikzpicture}

            \matrix[name=M, matrix of nodes, column sep=1cm, row sep=1cm]{
                \node[draw,minimum size=1cm]{IQ}; & \node[draw,minimum size=1cm]{Z}; \\
                \node[draw,minimum size=1cm]{JP}; & \node[draw,minimum size=1cm]{R}; \\
            };

            \draw[<->] (M-1-2) edge (M-2-2);
            \draw[<->] (M-1-1) edge (M-2-1);

        \end{tikzpicture}

    \subcaption{MCAR Mechanism}\label{fig:1b}
    \end{minipage}

    \caption{Figures}\label{fig:1}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is suggestive to use the `subfigure` environment with a usual `\caption` command instead of a `minipage` with `\subcaption`. As alternative there is the `\subcaptionbox` command.

Comment: Excellent job.. Thanks it works exactly the same way I wanted it

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that puts in an approximation of the upper left diagram.  By playing with the parameters you can get a better approximation.  Enlarge the boxes containing the characters and shrink slightly the boxes containing the frameboxes:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[barr,pdf]{xy}

\begin{document}
$$\bfig
 \node 1a(0,0)[\framebox{IQ}]
 \node 1b(400,0)[\framebox{Z}]
 \node 2a(0,-400)[\framebox{JP}]
 \node 2b(400,-400)[\framebox{R}]
 \arrow/<->/[1a`1b;]
 \arrow/<->/[1a`2a;]
 \arrow/<->/[1a`2b;]
 \arrow/<->/[2a`2b;]
 \arrow/<->/[1b`2b;]
 \efig$$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, don't use `$$` in LaTeX documents (at least not those you present here).

Comment: What does option `barr` to package `xy` do? I couldn't find it documented.

Answer (score 1):

after almost four years ... with use of `subfigure` environments and recent version of `tikz`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, matrix}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}% only for figure test
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \tikzset{
            > = Stealth,
Matrix/.style = {matrix of nodes,
                 nodes={draw, minimum size=10mm},
                 column sep=1cm, row sep=1cm}
            }
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\linewidth}
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [Matrix]
{
IQ  &   Z   \\
JP  &   R   \\
};
\draw[<->]  (m-1-2) edge (m-2-2)
            (m-1-1) edge (m-2-1)
            (m-1-1) edge (m-2-2)
            (m-2-1) edge (m-2-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{MNAR Mechanism}
    \label{fig:1a}
\end{subfigure}
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\linewidth}
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [Matrix]
{
IQ  &   Z   \\
JP  &   R   \\
};
\draw[<->]  (m-1-2) edge (m-2-2)
            (m-1-1) edge (m-2-1)
            (m-1-1) edge (m-2-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{NAR Mechanism}
    \label{fig:1b}
\end{subfigure}
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\linewidth}
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [Matrix]
{
IQ  &   Z   \\
JP  &   R   \\
};
\draw[<->]  (m-1-2) edge (m-2-2)
            (m-1-1) edge (m-2-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{MCAR Mechanism}
    \label{fig:1c}
\end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```